# When upgrading Angular 5 to 6, I get incompatible peer dependency (using ng update @angular/core)

Tags: angular, npm, angular5, angular6

I am trying to update my Angular app from v5 to v6 following [this guide](https://update.angular.io/).

I have ran all these commands successfully:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
npm install @angular/cli
ng update @angular/cli
```

The problem is that I get an error when running this command:

```
ng update @angular/core
                  Package "@angular/flex-layout" has an incompatible peer dependency to "rxjs" (requires "^5.5.0", would install "6.2.0").
                  Package "@angular/compiler-cli" has an incompatible peer dependency to "typescript" (requires ">=2.7.2 <2.8", would install "2.6.2")
Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
```

I am not sure how to handle this & I don't want to try things on my own to avoid breaking the app.

Can someone please advise what to do?

My current dependencies are as follows:

```
{
 ....
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.10",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.10",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^3.0.1",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "primeng": "^5.2.4",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.11",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.10",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.106",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.3.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: `"typescript" : "^2.7.2"` and update your `@angular/flex-layout` to the latest version. after that run `npm install`.

Comment: Actually @angular/flex-layout is the latest version already

Comment: That means the `@angular/flex-layout` is not compatible with `rxjs 6` you should choose one of them :).

Comment: Thanks Nour :) , I hope maybe someone can suggest some solution to use both

Comment: Did you update your rxjs to the latest version ? i see you are not. so try to update it using the same guide you provide. `npm install -g rxjs-tslint` and `rxjs-5-to-6-migrate -p src/tsconfig.app.json`

Comment: Thanks Nour, the 2 commands you mentioned should be done after updating the rxjs as far as I know, now I updated some dependencies with npm & it worked , thank you

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Hope this will help someone else, I finally could solve the issue by manually updating some of the angular packages (using npm)

```
npm i @angular/cdk@6 @angular/compiler-cli@6 @angular/material@6 rxjs@6 --save
```

After that the ng update command could work (with some warnings, but at least we passed the ng update @angular/core)

```
ng update @angular/core
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/language-service @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/animations @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/compiler @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/http @ "6.0.3" (was "5.2.10")...
UPDATE package.json (1587 bytes)
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@6.0.3 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.7.2 <2.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14 requires a peer of @angular/cdk@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14 requires a peer of @angular/core@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14 requires a peer of @angular/common@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @angular/flex-layout@5.0.0-beta.14 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.5.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@6.0.3 requires a peer of typescript@~2.4.0 || ~2.5.0 || ~2.6.0 || ~2.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ngx-translate/http-loader@3.0.1 requires a peer of @ngx-translate/core@>=10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN tsickle@0.27.5 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.4.2 <2.8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

updated 10 packages in 57.253s
```

Comment: ng update @angular/core@6 if targetting for v6 based on your other commands

Answer (score 58):

A work around for this would be to add a `--force` flag.

```
ng update @angular/core --force
```

Comment: However using `force` is usually not recommended

Comment: Agree with @AhmedElkoussy. Wouldn’t `force` leave out peer dependencies?

Answer (score 15):

The issue was solved for me after making a forced update like the following:-

```
ng update --all --force
```

It basically avoids/ignores all the dependency-checks and updates all the packages wherever applicable. **Although it is not recommended generally**, I had to do the update this way as other suggestions seemed to be not working for me.

Comment: not recommend this, mad a lot of problems with me, prefer update every package alone

Comment: Caused loads of issues for me too

Comment: Not suggestible

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get around messages about incompatible peers by using:

ng update --all

It updated all the packages that needed to be updated.

Comment: will it update based on angular current version? or the latest version? I am behind ng versions, so currently I am non ng 7 moving to ng 11. will ng update --all update based on ng 7 or ng 11?

Answer (score 2):

Running --force is not the right option. since it is complaining about rxjs and typescript, you need to upgrade that first. Once that's complete, you can run the angular update command

Answer (score 0):

Don't force update, that will later present unexpected results. Use the following npm install instead and try again.

```
npm install -g @angular-devkit/schematics-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
npm i --save-dev @angular/cli@version @angular/core@version
```

Then you can run `ng update --all`
This worked for me.

I got `Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.` while updating `@angular/cli` and `@angular/core` using `ng update --all`.

Answer (score 0):

this command worked in my case :

```
npm install --force @angular/cli@version @angular/core@version
```

here version could be 6,7,8,9,10 on which you to upgrade